# Polymorphism and explicit Casting

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism

I have the following architecture(*the analogy sucks but W/E*).

[image]

In `program` and other logic classes I have lots of methods that uses the specific type of the finger (`MonkeyFinger`). This mean that i have to explicitly cast in all those testMethods.

Is there any design pattern/solution to avoid explicit casts?

EDIT Code:

```
Monkey govi = new Monkey(...)
Program test = new Program()
test.testFinger1((MonkeyFinger) govi.GetHand.getFinger)
```

...

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: An animal has only one finger on one hand?

Comment: @YacoubMassad The actual Code is very complex, I have added some dummy code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know it should be a list of some Kind, but dont worry about the analogy.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to cast the return value of `getFinger` to `MonkeyFinger`? Is there something special in `MonkeyFinger`'s public interface that is not defined in `IFinger`?

Comment: Is there a class in your code that consumes `IFinger` regardless of its concrete type? Or does all your `IFinger` consumers expect a specific implementation of such interface? If this is the case, you can make the `Animal` class generic and have a generic type for the finger type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public class Animal<TFingerType> where TFingerType : IFinger
{
    Hand<TFingerType> GetHand() 
    {
        //... Do something
    }
}

public class Monkey : Animal<MonkeyFinger> { }
public class Hand<TFingerType> where TFingerType : IFinger
{

}
public interface IFinger
{

}
public class MonkeyFinger : IFinger {
}
```

At least in your given example, it doesn't make sense for a `Monkey` to return a hand which contains `HumanFinger`s. The hand itself is really defined by what type of fingers it has.

Then your code becomes:

```
Monkey govi = new Monkey(...)
Program test = new Program()
test.testFinger1(govi.GetHand.getFinger() /* getFinger here returns a MonkeyFinger */)
```

Note that the fingers are still `IFingers`, and can be used in that context, but this approach also provides concretely typed fingers.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but it turn out that i have to make lots of changes in the existing code to make this happen. In your opinion does this solution add some advantages over explicit Casting or altering existing working code is a bad idea?

Comment: @RayOldProf It depends, it's hard to make that call without seeing the actual code. If you're only casting for tests, I'd say it's probably not worth the effort to change over, since you said it'd require a large amount of effort. However, if you're casting in your real code, that may be a problem (as it stands, it's entirely possible that a `Monkey` returns a `Hand` which has `HumanFinger` instead of `MonkeyFinger`). Using templates means you're guaranteed to get a `MonkeyFinger` from a `Monkey`'s hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to create a method to do the checking for you. And yes, the casting is necessary if you want to test on some assumptions (like a monkey having only monkey fingers).

Something like:

```
public static T TestAndConvert<T>(object o)
{
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(o, typeof(T));

    return (T)o;
}
```

Here you first check if the type is correct and then you return a typed instance. This way you are sure the type is correct and you have proper testing.

Use it in your test calls:

```
testFinger1(TestAndConvert<MonkeyFinger>(finger));
```

(From your diagram I am not sure if you use an automated test framework, like Unit Tests in Visual Studio, I recommend to do so)

Comment: Not sure what benefit this assertion provides. Cast operator will already let you know whether the cast is valid or not by throwing exception.

Comment: It will give a better indicator in your test overview. An exception will usually tell you there is a code error in your test. An assert will show you that you have thought of it and that you can expect this to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a real need to pass concrete finger to test method? When you are using interface you are define a contract which each implementation should follow. You can extend parent behavior in child class (or replace it but it's not correspondent with [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))  with method overriding but you test only contract then why do you need to pass MonkeyFinger insted of IFinger in test method?